# How to get rows having sum equal to given in SQL

Tags: sql, excel

```
**Table A :**                 **Table B:**
ITEMCODE Total QTY        ITEMCODE Qty
A        100              A        25
B        50               A        75
C        75               B        10
D        85               B        20
                          B        30
                          D        80
                          D        5
```

Need to result view :

```
A   100  = A 25
           A 75
```

How to get this result with SQL function with these two tables

Comment: Why is this tagged 'Excel'?

Comment: I think his homework needs to output CSV to load to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the rows where the sum for the itemcode in `b` matches `a`.  One method uses window functions:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*, sum(qty) over (partition by itemcode) as sumqty
      from b
     ) b join
     a
     on a.itemcode = b.itemcode and a.qty = b.sumqty;
```